# Why is my VS2008 very slow at saving and renaming files

Tags: visual-studio-2008, plugins, performance

Windows Vista - using the following plugins - Codesmith and CodeKeep. 
I quess it started after installing the CodeSmith plugins ..

Comment: Have you uninstalled those addins and see if that was it?

Comment: Hi , thanks how to uninstall them ?

Comment: devenv.exe /SafeMode does not help neither  ; (

Comment: maybe it is because of an antivirus program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of addins